# ios7 didreceiveremotenotification not called when screen is locked

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification

I'm having a trouble to get the information from push notification and it only happens on iOS7, I have tested on iOS5 and iOS6, the function works perfectly fine. Here is the scenario: I have a game playing between 2 iPhones and it's a turn-base game, in every move, there will be a push notification sent to each competitor announce that the other one has made the move and now is your turn.

The problem is, when I lock my iPhone (turn off the screen) and the other made the move, there IS the push on my iPhone, and I slide to unlock, obviously the app appear but the 'didreceiveremotenotification' has not been invoked.

It's weird that only happens on iOS7. I know there are only 3 states that the application will get the push notification supspended/background/foreground. what state is the lockscreen? Any helps would be great and sorry for my English, if I didn't make it clear, please leave the comment, I will explain more.

Comment: This is not the way of asking something, it's impossible to read

Comment: I have this working in iOS7, you app would be in suspended state, post your method implementation

Comment: Does it happen only with locked screen? Or it happens also with unlocked screen but app in brackground?

Comment: It's only happens when the screen is locked, the app in background works perfectly